# How to access data from [[PromiseValue]] when using React hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to fetch data from my API and use it in different components via the Context API.

However, while I get a response back, it's under a Promise.[[PromiseValue]]. How would I correctly fetch this data so I can use it in my components?

```
import React,{useState, useEffect, createContext} from 'react';

export const ProductsContext = createContext();

export const ProductsProvider = props => {
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState({ categories: {} });
    const [products, setProducts] = useState({ products: {} });
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    useEffect(() => {

        (async () => {
            const [categoriesResult, productsResult] = await Promise.all([fetch('/api/categories'), fetch('/api/products')]);
            setCategories(categoriesResult.json());
            setProducts(productsResult.json());
            setLoading(false);
          })(); 
        }, []);
    return (
        <ProductsContext.Provider value={ { products, categories, loading } }>
            {props.children}
        </ProductsContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

When trying to access the data within the context, I get the response successfully, however it's in a `[[PromiseValue]]`

```
import React from 'react';
import ProductsContainer from './Products/ProductsContainer';
import {ProductsProvider} from './Products/ProductsContext';
const Page = () => (

    <>
      <Header/>
      <Banner/>
      <ProductsProvider>
        <ProductsContainer/>
      </ProductsProvider>
    </>

);

export default Page;


import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { ProductsContext } from './ProductsContext';


const Products = () => {
    const {products, categories, loading} = useContext(ProductsContext);
    return (
        <div className="products">
            {
                console.log(products)
            }
        </div>
    ); 
};

export default Products;
```

I get the response:

[image]

Comment: See also http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html. Write a wrapper function around `fetch`, response checking, and the json parsing, then call that function in the `Promise.all`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.json()` function for responses coming out of `fetch` is asynchronous, so when you setting your context state with `setXXX(xxx.json())` you're setting it to a promise.

To access the resolved value within the promise, change it to `setXXX(await xxx.json())` and you'll be able to access to array of data you're looking for from within your function component that's hooked into the context.